# Calling SOAP API with iOS SDK

Tags: soap-api, ios

Is there a way to call a SOAP API method (convertLead in particular) using the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I just added support for convertLead to [ZKSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce) which is usable from iOS & OSX